# Unwanted background in h2 in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, background

I have a page in which i am using accordion, h2 and other ul li stuff.

Im older versions of IE my page is having an issue. On load it comes with unwanted background color and border in `<h2>` but when i click on accordion and expand the page the background gets disapper and page is fine i am not sure why this is happening when i haven't given any background in `<h2>` element.

This is onload image

[image]

This image when i use accordion once

[image]

Any idea why it is happening and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you got a link so we can inspect?

Comment: I haven't got an old version of IE with me at the moment so I can't test but try removing the opacity value:

   ` .faq_inner h2.faq_heading {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        /* opacity: .5; */
        font-weight: 400;
    }`

Comment: but what is the problem with opacity?? IE old version don't even support opacity i will just ignore it.

Comment: The only thing it is doing is making the text a grey instead of black. if you want the text to be grey just use color:#eee;

Comment: already using `color` property..